# Compiler settings for template header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My Visual Studio project contains header template files and for some of them I want to set the /ARCH parameter. Unfortunately I cannot do that for header files in Visual Studio. Is there a way to define this parameter for single template header files?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to set compiler flags for header files, since they are not compiled by themselves. Instead they are included into source files to form [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) which are then compiled.

Comment: What would happen if I switch the element type from header file to C/C++ compiler?

Comment: Even if you change type from header file to source file and build them, the generated code won't be possible to use. A header file can only be used as a header tile, and to be included as a part of a larger translation unit.

Comment: And perhaps it's time for you to ask about your *real* problem instead? *Why* do you want to set the `/ARCH` flag for those header files? What problem is that supposed to solve? Right now this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It doesn't make sense to set compiler flags for header files, since they are not compiled by themselves. Instead they are included into source files to form translation units which are then compiled.

~ @Someprogrammerdude